# AWS Aurora missing metrics like "[Billed] Volume Read IOPS (Count), [Billed] Volume Read IOPS (Count)" etc in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora

I'm missing metrics like [Billed] Volume Read IOPS (Count), [Billed] Volume Read IOPS (Count) in CloudWatch.

Although these metrics are visible in RDS -> CloudWatch.
[RDS CloudWatch metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SS8s.png)

Is it possible the find these metrics in CloudWatch so I can create alarm for them?

**Update:**
it turns out that these metrics are available as:

```
VolumeBytesUsed -> [Billed] Volume bytes used
VolumeReadIOPs -> [Billed] Volume read IOPs
VolumeWriteIOPs -> [Billed] Volume write IOPs
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.Metrics.RDSAvailability.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These metrics are available as `VolumeBytesUsed`, `VolumeReadIOPs`, `VolumeWriteIOPs` (note the "Volume" prefix).

I will take the opportunity to point out that "IOPS" is a misnomer for these metrics; they are really "IOP5M" or "IOs per 5 minutes." (Thanks, AWS.)

Therefore there is a ~300x difference between `ReadIOPs` and `VolumeReadIOPs`.

There is not a linear relationship between `WriteIOPs` and `VolumeWriteIOPs` because the latter is boxcared into 8KB(?) chunks and the former is not.

Very confusing, but I hope that helps.